# Filter ObservableCollection based on checkbox listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, observablecollection

I can't find any nice solution to solve my problem. All that I think about are good but to long I guess. So here is the thing:

I have map with pushpins binded from ObservableCollection and filter ApplicationBar button on bottow which navigates to set filters page.

Filters page is listbox with checkboxes. Based on which checkboxes are checked I want to filter my pushpins on map.

And btw. my pins data comes from sqlite. So generaly I can do WHERE type = 'name1' OR WHERE type='name2' and it will do it well.

The only thing I am missing here is how to fill this query, I mean how to get values from listbox and smoothly send them to my map page.

I hope that wasn't too chaotic :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the ICollectionView interface : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752348.aspx

Comment: the problem is that my sqlite records are saved in ObservableCollection

Comment: you can create a ICollectionView from an ObservableCollection.